# Is it normal that puppet needs 20 seconds to apply simple manifest?

Tags: freebsd, puppet

it's `FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE amd64` in here. I installed puppet from ports and my manifest also probably uses ports packages. I'm happy with that. Now here's a simple manifest:

```
root@ovh:/root # cat freebsd.pp
package { '*./editors/vim':
    ensure => installed,
}
```

Applying manifest:

```
root@ovh:/root # puppet apply freebsd.pp
Notice: /Stage[main]//Package[*./editors/vim]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 22.54 seconds
```

23 seconds to execute simple package check which actually already installed??? 
Is this normal? I'm new to puppet, so if somebody can explain what's going on in background for such a simple check, I would really appreciate that. Maybe there's faster way to check if package installed?

Comment: have you tried running puppet with the `--debug` switch? That should give you more detail about what's going on.

Comment: ok with debug i see that puppet every time adds package with pkg_add, and there's really lots of stuff going on in there.. would be nice if puppet could use ports. is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding debug switch I see that vim installed every time with pkg_add. So this question is answered.

```
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderRug: file /usr/bin/rug does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPortage: file /usr/bin/emerge does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPkgin: file pkgin does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderHpux: file /usr/sbin/swinstall does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderNim: file /usr/sbin/nimclient does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAptrpm: file apt-get does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderFink: file /sw/bin/fink does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderUp2date: file /usr/sbin/up2date-nox does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderRpm: file rpm does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderYum: file rpm does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPkg: file /usr/bin/pkg does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: file /usr/bin/apt-get does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderSun: file /usr/sbin/pkgrm does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderDpkg: file /usr/bin/dpkg does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPacman: file /usr/bin/pacman does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAptitude: file /usr/bin/aptitude does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderZypper: file /usr/bin/zypper does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderUrpmi: file urpmq does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderSunfreeware: file pkg-get does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAix: file /usr/bin/lslpp does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Creating default schedules[0m
[0;36mDebug: Failed to load library 'selinux' for feature 'selinux'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'client_datadir': 'File[/var/puppet/client_data]{:backup=>false, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/puppet/client_data", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Failed to load library 'shadow' for feature 'libshadow'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUseradd: file usermod does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file usermod does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false[0m
[0;36mDebug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/uuidgen does not exist[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'certdir': 'File[/var/puppet/ssl/certs]{:owner=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :path=>"/var/puppet/ssl/certs", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'vardir': 'File[/var/puppet]{:backup=>false, :path=>"/var/puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'requestdir': 'File[/var/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]{:owner=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :path=>"/var/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rundir': 'File[/var/run/puppet]{:backup=>false, :mode=>"1777", :path=>"/var/run/puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'plugindest': 'File[/var/puppet/lib]{:backup=>false, :path=>"/var/puppet/lib", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statefile': 'File[/var/puppet/state/state.yaml]{:backup=>false, :mode=>"660", :path=>"/var/puppet/state/state.yaml", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostprivkey': 'File[/var/puppet/ssl/private_keys/ovh.holms.lt.pem]{:owner=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :mode=>"600", :path=>"/var/puppet/ssl/private_keys/ovh.holms.lt.pem", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientbucketdir': 'File[/var/puppet/clientbucket]{:backup=>false, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/puppet/clientbucket", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statedir': 'File[/var/puppet/state]{:backup=>false, :mode=>"1755", :path=>"/var/puppet/state", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunfile': 'File[/var/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]{:backup=>false, :mode=>"644", :path=>"/var/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'logdir': 'File[/var/puppet/log]{:owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/puppet/log", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'ssldir': 'File[/var/puppet/ssl]{:owner=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :mode=>"771", :path=>"/var/puppet/ssl", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'graphdir': 'File[/var/puppet/state/graphs]{:backup=>false, :path=>"/var/puppet/state/graphs", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatekeydir': 'File[/var/puppet/ssl/private_keys]{:owner=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/puppet/ssl/private_keys", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientyamldir': 'File[/var/puppet/client_yaml]{:backup=>false, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/puppet/client_yaml", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostpubkey': 'File[/var/puppet/ssl/public_keys/ovh.holms.lt.pem]{:owner=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :mode=>"644", :path=>"/var/puppet/ssl/public_keys/ovh.holms.lt.pem", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunreport': 'File[/var/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]{:backup=>false, :mode=>"640", :path=>"/var/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'confdir': 'File[/usr/local/etc/puppet]{:backup=>false, :path=>"/usr/local/etc/puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'publickeydir': 'File[/var/puppet/ssl/public_keys]{:owner=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :path=>"/var/puppet/ssl/public_keys", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatedir': 'File[/var/puppet/ssl/private]{:owner=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/puppet/ssl/private", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet/ssl][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet/ssl][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/clientbucket]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/ssl/private_keys/ovh.holms.lt.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet/ssl/private_keys][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet/ssl][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/ssl/public_keys/ovh.holms.lt.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet/ssl/public_keys][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet/ssl][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/state/graphs]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet/state][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/client_data]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/log]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet/state][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/state/state.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet/state][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet/state][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet/ssl][0m
[0;36mDebug: /File[/var/puppet/client_yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/puppet][0m
[0;36mDebug: Finishing transaction 17233557220[0m
[0;36mDebug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds[0m
[0;36mDebug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds[0m
[0;32mInfo: Applying configuration version '1360078391'[0m
[0;36mDebug: /Schedule[daily]: Skipping device resources because running on a host[0m
[0;36mDebug: /Schedule[monthly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host[0m
[0;36mDebug: /Schedule[hourly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host[0m
[0;36mDebug: /Schedule[never]: Skipping device resources because running on a host[0m
[0;36mDebug: /Schedule[weekly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host[0m
[0;36mDebug: /Schedule[puppet]: Skipping device resources because running on a host[0m
[0;36mDebug: Prefetching freebsd resources for package[0m
[0;36mDebug: Executing '/usr/sbin/pkg_info -aoQ'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Executing '/usr/sbin/pkg_info -aoQ'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Package: *./editors/vim: origin => {:port_category=>"editors", :port_name=>"vim"}[0m
[0;36mDebug: Package: *./editors/vim: source => #<URI::FTP:0x80648c4d0 URL:ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/%2Fpub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-9-stable/>[0m
[0;36mDebug: Fetching INDEX: #<URI::FTP:0x80648b1c0 URL:ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-9-stable/INDEX.bz2>[0m
[0;36mDebug: Package: *./editors/vim: package_uri => #<URI::FTP:0x80a1b3980 URL:ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-9-stable/All/vim-7.3.669.tbz>[0m
[0;36mDebug: Executing '/usr/sbin/pkg_add -f ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-9-stable/All/vim-7.3.669.tbz'[0m
[mNotice: /Stage[main]//Package[*./editors/vim]/ensure: created[0m
[0;36mDebug: /Stage[main]//Package[*./editors/vim]: The container Class[Main] will propagate my refresh event[0m
[0;36mDebug: Class[Main]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event[0m
[0;36mDebug: Finishing transaction 17232926340[0m
[0;36mDebug: Storing state[0m
[0;36mDebug: Stored state in 0.02 seconds[0m
[mNotice: Finished catalog run in 21.05 seconds[0m
[0;36mDebug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rrddir': 'File[/var/puppet/rrd]{:owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/puppet/rrd", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow}'[0m
[0;36mDebug: Finishing transaction 17264361120[0m
[0;36mDebug: Received report to process from ovh.holms.lt[0m
[0;36mDebug: Processing report from ovh.holms.lt with processor Puppet::Reports::Store[0m
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes since you installed a new package.. run it again and the created should go away and it will be a little faster. Puppet is not very fast anyway. For that package it has to query your package manager to see if it is installed and if you don't select one it will take it's best guess at what it should be try that and if that isn't there pick the next best guess.

Comment: actually it's `created` every time I run it. That's odd